# Why is it said about limits of functions that the input approaches some value but never reaches it?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

From what I understand, a convergent sequence can have among its terms its own limit (even more than once.) It may also not have it, this has no bearing on whether a sequence fits the definition of being convergent or not. But when we talk about the limit of a function from reals to reals, as the input approaches some value in the domain, I have seen it said in many places that the input approaches the said value but never actually takes on/reaches that value.

Now if we think of the term "approach" as describing a sequence of input values that converge to some value, as I have said above, such a sequence may incude its limit i.e. the value it approaches among its terms, however this is not allowed in the definitions of limits in functions I have read and I suppose there has to be a reason why, which I cannot figure out.

Comment: If $f(x)=x+3$ and you ask what is $\lim\limits_{x \to 3} f(x)$ then the answer is obviously $6$, since $f(x)$ is a continuous function and $f(3)=6$.  If on the other hand you have the similar  $g(x)=\frac{x^2-9}{x-3}$ when $x \not=3$ (but not when $x=3$ as it would suggest $\frac00$), then you also have $\lim\limits_{x \to 3} g(x)=6$ no matter what the value $g(3)$ takes.

Comment: @Henry So can we say that the restriction of the input value from taking on the value it approaches, in the context of function limits, is a convention/rule so that scenarios where undefined results emerge are avoided?

Comment: I have never seen a definition of limit, which doesn't allow the function not to "reach the limit",  I have heard it a couple of times, when someone needs to explain the concept of limits to students, where it is important to understand that the function doesn't necessarily reach it's limit, but this doesn't mean that it cannot happen.  Take for instance the limit of $f(x) = 0$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen I think the issue I'm referring to is different: The function itself may reach its limit as in the example you've given.  I am referring to the fact that the expression "as the variable/input approaches some constant" means that the variable is never assumed to be exactly that constant, however close to it it may be brought.

Comment: @jacob78 Ah sorry i misunderstood your question. But then your analogy of sequences doesn't quite work. The value of a sequence can indeed reach it's limit. But the input of a sequence (or index), is a natural number $n$, which never reaches $\infty$, which is one of the reasons why we say approaches $\infty$ instead.

Comment: I think my question can be rephrased as follows: In the epsilon-delta definition of limit of a function, why is it specified that the distance between the input and the constant it approaches is not only smaller than delta, but also greater than zero.

Comment: Actually, for a sequence limit, typically $n\to\infty$, and $\infty$ is not a possible input value. You can't talk about the term $a_\infty$.

Comment: Your post has a lot of words but no symbols. This makes it hard to understand what you are asking. For instance, if you are wondering about $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ then the comment of @paw88789 is appropriate regarding $n$ approaching $\infty$. And if you are wondering about $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=L$ then a similar comment could apply regarding $x$ approaching $c$. But in both cases, a particular value of $x_n$, or of $f(x)$, could indeed be equal to $L$.

Comment: @LeeMosher In the second case you mentioned, where x approaches c, the limit of f equals L, is it not by definition that x approaches c arbitrarily, but never actually "reaches" c i.e., the variable x never assumes the value c?

Comment: Yes, that's correct about how $x$ approaches $c$. If that's what you are asking about, you could *greatly* clarify your post by hitting the edit button and rewriting it.

Comment: But if you are asking about something other than how $x$ approaches $c$, then I still wonder what you are actually asking, and you could clarify that as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit inaccurate to say that the function, or even sequence, *never* reaches its limit value. More accurately, we would say that it is never *required* to reach its limit, only that we can get arbitrarily close to it. A simple counterexample of the statement is any constant function - quite obviously in that case the limit is always equal to every value of the function, and similarly for a constant sequence.

The reason for this is to have a definition of limit that allows us to apply it in cases where the function doesn't exist at a given point, or is discontinuous at that point. Compare the following three functions:

$$\begin{eqnarray}f_1(x) & = & x + 2 \\
f_2(x) & = & \begin{cases} x + 2 & x \neq 2 \\
17 & x = 2 \end{cases} \\
f_3(x) & = & \frac{x^2 - 4}{x - 2}
\end{eqnarray}$$

In all three cases, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} f_i(x) = 4$. However, $f_1(2) = 4$, $f_2(2) = 17$ and $f_3(2)$ isn't defined. If we changed the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit to include the $\delta = 0$ case, then only $\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} f_1(x) = 4$ would be true - and in general the definition would only work for continuous functions, which would mean we'd need some other language to talk about functions like $f_2$ and $f_3$.

Comment: I think this gives me the answer I was looking for. Just to reiterate it to make sure we are on the same page though: The wording we use when talking about limits where we say "the input approaches some value", in the context of functional limits, it is by definition that we mean the input never actually reaches that value, which means, if we were to express the input approaching that certain value by a sequence whose limit is that certain value, that sequence would never "reach" its limit i.e., it would not have it as a term. (This is not a property held by all sequences by any means.)

Comment: It would not need to ever have its limit as a value, that is true.